# Regular Expressions - Not letters and not only zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looking for this regular expression for a long time but I still can't found it.

I need a regular expression that match only numbers and not letters and not only zeros.
Ex:

```
0000 => no  
00001 => yes  
0000a => no  
10000 => yes
111 / 333 - 111 => yes
```

I think is clear.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to capture? If a number appears other than 0 you want to grab the whole string including 0, or do you just want the difference?

Comment: In my work, people sometimes have to write his phones numbers and my boss want to capture what I describe. I know it's difficult but if boss want I have to do jaja.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the string starts and ends with only the non zero number, `/^\d*[1-9]+\d*$/` will do the trick.

You can try this out at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oZIjD6/10

- `^` means that the string must start with this expression
- `\d*` matches any number between 0 and infinite times
- `[1-9]+` will match a non zero number more than once (so no only zeros numbers will match)
- `$` means the string must end with this expression

Comment: This doesn't take into account the last case at all

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that they only want to match the value of the expression, not whole expression itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but don't match. For example: "00000 / aaaa" shoud be invalid and is matching

Comment: ajaja but you've change the regex options. how I set this in js?

Comment: The example I just linked does not need any flags to work.

Comment: Yes because in that case it requires multi line matching, adding `mg` after your regex expression will make it match in that case, however it is not required if each match is on a different string.

Comment: I would guess this is not working for you because you are declaring your regex with `var re = new RegExp()`, however all you need is `var re =  /^\d*[1-9]+\d*$/`

Comment: does not matter, will be single line, and is not matching. what could be the error? https://regex101.com/r/oZIjD6/13

Comment: It was not designed to handle slashes, `/^[\d\/\-\s]*[1-9]+[\d\/\-\s]*$/` will handle them.